# Crisping prosciutto

Tags: baking, frying, ham

This may seem like an obvious question, but I have a couple of recipes that I make a lot that require crumbling crisped prosciutto over / in them.

Whilst I have experimented with many frying / baking techniques to crisp the prosciutto to a consistency that will crumble nicely without being burnt, oily or rubbery, I have never quite perfected it.

Does anyone have any tips that may help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this with both diced prosciutto and thinly sliced prosciutto. For the diced, tossing in a little oil and searing seems to work best. For the thinly sliced, popping it on a cast iron surface and placing it in a 350 degree oven does very nicely.

Comment: A little oil gets those small chunks really going. Works for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

When I want prosciutto to crumble, I take thin slices and deep fry until completely desiccated. Dry well on two changes of paper towel (or cloth), then crumble when cooled.

Answer (score 2):

I always do bacon in the microwave, on a plate, between paper towels.  It's quick and the doneness is very controllable.  Maybe try that with prosciutto bits?

Comment: I've never tried that, I've taken to lightly baking in the oven for best results, but I will give it a try. Thanks